# Delete folder with infinite items

Tags: sd-card, data-corruption

Right after copying a folder to my SD card, I unmounted it and removed it from the slot. The problem is, I removed it *before* it was done unmounting, and now that folder is now named "ELEILE" (from "engine") and has (supposedly) infinite items, with totally invalid names (e.g.: "╓|?≤^?≈E.DZ$", "µ?╟ g╥▒τ.?ü", "j+e?»░a?.b\2"), and reports 6.6TB of size, though the SD is only 16GB, which made it think it has only 11MB free (which doesn't make much sense either).

Everytime I try to do anything related to it (delete, rename, copy, or even check the properties), it starts thinking that the filesystem is read-only, and I must reinsert it if I want to modify anything.

Opening the SD in something like FBI (3DS homebrew) shows the folder normally as "engine", and lists its child folders correctly too, but the files are missing and the size is still crazy, so no hope.

I've been researching this for quite a while, but nobody has the same issue as me. My question is: how do I delete it?

Comment: If the file system is corrupt as it seems to be the better you can do is just format it.

Comment: **(Format or fix)** If you have other date you want to keep answer this.  What is the partition name and type where the file is on the card?  If you don't now run this and add the output to your question:  `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid&&sudo parted -l`

Comment: It's FAT32, and what do you mean by name? It's at /dev/sdb, if that's what you want

Comment: The card is working normally, the problem is just that immense folder. It has about 7GB of data, which I want to keep. It's my 3DS's card, and I don't want to redownload all my games.

Comment: Partitions have names.  That's why I mentioned if you didn't know the name or other information to run the command which would provide what's needed.  What you mentioned should be sufficient.  As far as names, run the command and you'll see the type of information drives can have.  You hadn't mention any of that information in your question.  I didn't want to just assume you had not formatted it in any special way.

Comment: No, I didn't format it in any special way, and that's if I even formatted it at all.

Comment: Knowing the drive letter would help.  That is the type of information the requested output would show.

Comment: I told you: if the device is at /dev/sdb, then the letter is b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this from the terminal:

<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
$ sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/[drive and partition]
```

Replace the drive and partition with the drive and partition of your device.

You can get this information with this command:

```
sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid&&sudo parted -l
```

The output will reveal a partition similar to: `/dev/sdb1`.

The results from the chat is revealing that the usb drive's partition is clean.  The problem is with the directories under the 3ds folder.  Since that folder can't be processed the alternative is to backup the the content of the drive while skipping the offending folder.

Below is a script and steps to do this:

Make a backup folder:

```
$ sudo mkdir /usbbackup
$ chwon $(whoami) /usbbackup
```

The folder can be any place on your system.  The second command is giving your account access to the folder.

Change the settings in the script to these settings:

- `source     - The name of the mount point of the usb drive`
- `dest       - The destination folder.`
- `skipfolder - The problem folder that is being skipped`

**The backup script**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source=/media/joaovictor/9016-4EF8/
dest=/usbbackup
skipfolder=3ds

ls $source | while read -r item;do
    # echo $item
    if [[ $item == $skipfolder ]]; then
        # echo $item
        continue
    fi
    echo "$source/$item -> $dest"
    cp -pvau "$source/$item" "$dest"
done

echo "Finished"
```

Comment: It reports "fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)                                                                                                                                                                    
Logical sector size is zero."

Comment: I don't think the problem is the filesystem, it's working fine, except it has much less space

Comment: I'm formating a usb drive with fat32 and will provide the details.

Comment: If would help if you would provide the output of `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid&&sudo parted -l`.  I can ensure I have the same type of format and partitions (if any) as you.  Also, there is a chance the output might show errors.

Comment: @jv110 I updated the answer based on test from my computer.

Comment: Primary file system, 512B sector size, msdos partition table, vfat FSTYPE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54387/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-jv110).